# How do I keep my node.js site online 24/7 while using replit

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I’ve been trying to keep my node.js site online

i tried uptime robot but my site went down after 5 minutes.

The site is hosted on replit because I’ve been coding it on my school ipad in my free time.

If there’s anyways you guys know please answer this post.

Comment: From what I could read, replit is more of a development environment. You should not use it for production purpose. There is a ton of ways to host node js site, you should try to do some research on the subject. Stackoverflow is not the place to discuss such topic, but i'm sure you can find many resources online about this very subject.

Comment: I wouldn't expect Replit to host your server for you for free.  (Unless you can point to somewhere that they claim to support that.)  If you want to host a server you'd either host it on your computer or find a hosting service for it.

Comment: Replit lets u host it free the problme is its not 24/7 u have to either visit the site or ping it i need like a site that pings a site every 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You could host it in a virtual machine on https://www.oracle.com/cloud/sign-in.html. One downside to that is that you have to configure the server youself. But once it is up and running you can upload your files to the server via ftp or as a docker container you publish on some registry.
Oracle Cloud has a very generous always free plan. (Credit Card needed for the account, but you can use always free resources if you want and you won't be charged for anything.)

You could also host it on https://glitch.com/pricing if it is a static site.
If it is just a website, you could also host it on vercel or on netlify.

Comment: Replit lets u host it free the problme is its not 24/7 u have to either visit the site or ping it i need like a site that pings a site every 5 minutes

Comment: You could use https://betterstack.com/uptime (pings every 3 minutes). But I am not sure if that solves your problem. Just download the code and host it on a free hosting service.